# Can someone help me with thie error? InvalidOperationException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net

This is my module where I made the connection 
[image: This is my module where I made the connection]

here is the error i get 
[image: here is the error i get]

Which roughly translates to:

```
ExecuteReader: The CommandText property has not been initialized
```

I'm not very experimented in this so f you can help me it would be amazing.
I'm trying to make inventory and sales program that can take track of payments for each client that have credit.

Ill paste my code.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TelasDataSet2.Vendedor' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.VendedorTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TelasDataSet2.Vendedor)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        con.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, con)
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Telas")
        qry = "Insert into vendedor values("
        qry &= TextBox1.Text
        qry &= ","
        qry &= TextBox2.Text
        qry &= ")"

    End Sub

End Class
```

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1
    Public str As String = GetConString()
    Public con As New SqlConnection(str)
    Public cmd As SqlCommand
    Public da As SqlDataAdapter
    Public ds As DataSet
    Public bs As BindingSource
    Public qry As String

    Public Function GetConString() As String
        Return "Data Source=daniel\sqlexpress01;" &
               "Initial Catalog=Telas;" &
               "Integrated Security=True"

    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please don't post links to images of code and or errors, put them in your post.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that you never initialized the `CommandText` property.  Which you haven't.  You create a command here:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, con)
```

But at this time the `qry` variable is empty.  So there's no SQL command to execute.

It looks like you're trying to create a command *after* you execute it.  You need to create it *before* you execute it.  A couple other important notes include:

1. The command you're creating is *highly vulnerable* to **SQL injection**.  You should use parameterized queries instead.
2. You're creating an `INSERT` command and trying to fill a `DataSet` with the results.  That doesn't make much sense.  `SELECT` commands produce data, `INSERT` commands only produce a success/fail result.
3. Anything which implements `IDisposable` should be disposed after it's used.  And [the `Using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) makes that easy.  In general, objects like `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` shouldn't be shared among multiple methods or re-used like this.  Create them, use them, and dispose of them in a small scope.  The heavy lifting of creating and opening connections is already optimized by the system under the hood, and the potential bugs of re-using these objects far outweight the absolutely miniscule performance improvement you might be getting.

Comment: I know it's not the issue of course, but expanding on your important notes, objects that implement `IDisposable` should be disposed of as well and good post David.